# Disable future dates in date time picker in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using this plugin for date time picker

Link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datetimepicker

Demo Link :

https://jx7cx.csb.app/

I want to disable future dates,

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: try element/ant?  they have props to fit into your requirements

Comment: @fengxh: I have used the same date time picker in other places also, can u please give a link to disable future dates with this plugin

Comment: sorry, i haven't used that plugin before. and i also don't find any configuration you can use to disable futuer dates in that plugin's npm docs.

Comment: +1 to @fengxh. I think there is not a configuration of the component by itself. Maybe as a workaround you can try an approach of watching the value of the variable and validate if is a future date when changed, reseting the value and displaying and information message.